# For small input spaces, are arrays or sets quicker when checking for membership?

Tags: arrays, hash, set, big-o, hashset

This question has been bugging me for a while: If I’m checking for membership and I only have <10 elements, is a hash map still the fastest option? In other words, when N is guaranteed to be **small**, which of these Python operations is faster:

• `x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

• `x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`

My intuition behind asking this is that computing the hash would be inefficient for small input spaces.

Comment: It's all about number of searches, not about collection size. Array search has O(N) complexity and hash search has O(1) complexity. Computing a hash gives you some overhead so when you search only once it's slower, yes. But when you search multiple times, hash search is apparently much more efficient

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko hmmm, so are you saying if I was only going to make one search on a small input space, an array is faster; but on subsequent searches, no matter the input size, hash sets will always be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Sets are less efficient than arrays for small search space. I ran a test that checks for the membership of an element in a set and in an array for 10000 times each. The element is not present, so it has to check the whole array.
The results are:

1000 elements
Time for set:
1.06799983978
Time for array:
4.13400006294

100 elements
Time for set:
1.05599999428
Time for array:
1.19999980927

70 elements
Time for set:
1.09599995613
Time for array:
1.09200000763

10 elements:
Time for set:
1.1360001564
Time for array:
0.927999973297

So, for checking the membership of an element in a set of fewer than 70 elements, using an array is more efficient than using sets.

Comment: that's interesting and it confirms what I was thinking...why do you think an array is more efficient when N < 70?